# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise installation error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am having difficulty in installing **Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise (Update 1)**. After installation completes, I get a warning saying **"Not all features installed correctly"**. See below snip for details

[image]

In control panel programs list I found that VC++ 14.0.23506 (both x64 and x86) are installed.

I am able to open visual studio, but when I try to create a new project I get following error regrading c# compiler error

[image]

I know performing a clean install again is a solution, but I have poor internet speed and would like to avoid downloading the whole thing again. Any help in fixing this would be great.

PS: I have VS 2013 professional and VS 2012 express also installed, both of which are working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling Visual Studio 2015, those VC++ 2015 x86 and x64 runtimes, and reinstalling Visual Studio 2015. Looks like it didn't finish installing properly because you already had the runtimes installed.

Comment: But simply unistalling VC++ 2015 without modifiying appropriate registry keys might create even more problems